# Code executing on the same thread but different process

Tags: python-3.x

Can someone explain why this code executes on the same thread but on different processes? How is that possible?

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import os
import threading


def whereami():
    print("You are on thread {} and on process {}".format(
        threading.get_ident(), os.getpid()))


with ProcessPoolExecutor() as pool:
    whereami()
    pool.submit(whereami)
```